# BackgroundImage repeat + rounded corners

Tags: java, android, rounded-corners

So I should display a schedule, where every item has a background image with rounded corners...

I can't find out how to give my view (currently a TextView but I could change that) a background (which is a pattern that has to be repeated) and give it rounded corners...

All I can find is how to give rounded corners with a solid background color...

Could anyone help out?

EDIT: backgroundimage looks like this http://www.photoshop-pack.com/tutorials/images/1145.gif

---

A background image with rounded corners: not all items on the schedule have the same length

Left corners + main bg + Right corners: bg should repeat so the right corners wouldnt lineup with the center bg

Comment: I think I answered this same question [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15148400/714249

Answer (score 3):

Some thing similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<LinearLayout 
     android:padding="4dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bkg_rounded"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="hello all how are you ? "
    android:background="@drawable/back_repeat"
    />
</LinearLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

I got something like this
[image: rounded pattern]

Comment: here list_bkg_rounded is an xml  which draws rounded corners

Comment: I keep getting: <bitmap> requires a valid src attribute... Refreshed, cleaned, removed image, added again,... nothing works any idea?

Comment: did u add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> in u r <bitmap>   XML file ?

Comment: Yes copied it all... Weird, but it's alright will use squares instead of rounded corners.. Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 1):

let me post my code here 
I have back_repeat.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/repeat" 
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

and repeat.gif in drawable folder which is backgroundimage from u r link.

also  list_bkg_rounded.xml  in drawable folder which is rounded border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#fc9700"/>
     <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
     <solid android:color="#fc9700"/>
 </shape>
```

and my main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<LinearLayout 
     android:padding="4dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bkg_rounded"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="hello all how are you ? "
    android:background="@drawable/back_repeat"
    />
</LinearLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Will try this out in the morning, can't see alot of difference with my code but you'll never know... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> A background image with rounded corners: not all items on the schedule have the same length
>
> Left corners + main bg + Right corners: bg should repeat so the right corners wouldnt lineup with the center bg

can u post layout image ?

Comment: See edit: background image looks like http://www.photoshop-pack.com/tutorials/images/1145.gif

Comment: create a xml like following <bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/scale1"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true" />        http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/06/how-to-tile-background-image-in-android.html      check this link    http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/06/how-to-tile-background-image-in-android.html

Comment: And what about the rounded corners? (thanks in advance) I know how to set a background+repeat it just rounded corners are a pain in the ass!

Comment: try adding another Linear Layout which will hold the above