# Bitmap repeat + top left and bottom left rounded background

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap, android-background

I could make bitmap to repeat and 4 side rounded background with the help of this question (first answer)
[Bitmap repeat + rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675161/bitmap-repeat-rounded-corners)

But I need only top left and bottom left to be rounded. How to achieve this?